# How to draw horizontal stacked bar chart in MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.
Here I am unable to drawn horizontal stacked bar chart

Comment: please add some reference code, what have you tried so far? what has gone wrong? any exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The horizontal-stacked barchart works just like the normal stacked `BarChart`, except that you have to use `HorizontalBarChart`.

- You can [check out the example here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/HorizontalBarChartActivity.java)
- And [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#barchart) you can find a detailed tutorial